# Rails, urls without controller for both posts and pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rails blog app, I have posts and pages. I am using friendly_id gem. Is it possible to have clean URLs without the controller for both post and pages at the same time? They should look like that:

example.com/my-post
example.com/my-page

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, but you will need to be extremly carefully to avoid duplicate slugs between pages and posts.

**routes.rb**

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get ':id', to: 'pages_posts#show', as: 'page_or_post'
end
```

**pages_posts_controller.rb**

```rb
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if @page = Page.friendly.find(params[:id])
      render 'pages/show'
    elsif @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
      render 'posts/show'
    else
      raise ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    end
  end
end
```

***.html.erb**

```rb
link_to 'link', page_or_post_path(id: object.slug)
```